# Splitting dates in SQL

Tags: sql

I wanted to if there is a query that will split and group the dates in an SQL table by month.

I made a spreadsheet of purchases with the name, order date, purchase total, etc.  I attached an image of a spreadsheet below

```
 select total_sales count(*) from SalesChart 
 where month(purchase_date) = 1
```

[image]

Comment: In your example records are sorting by month, is it what you want to get? If not - then please show a piece of data as you want it to see

Comment: Please edit your question by adding a tag for your database platform? Date functions and syntax tend to vary between platforms.

Comment: group by `month(purchase Date), year(Purchase date)`?  maybe you don't care about different years though?  or use a window function `count(*) Over (partition by month(purchase_date)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `sum(item-purchase)` based months from a datetime then query :

```
   SELECT firstname , sum([item-purchased]), datepart(month,purchase_date)
FROM SalesChart 
  group by  firstname , datepart(month,purchase_date)
  order by  datepart(month,purchase_date) asc
```

Output is :

```
Max     4   1
lena    13  2
mona    9   3
Emy     7   4
Steve   5   4
lee     3   6
Frank   1   12
```

I've created a sql fiddle with sample data like your list Please check this [Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c0a03/4/0)

Comment: I never seen anyone want or need to order months *alphabetically*. Consider ordering my month *number*

Comment: in our Fa-IR culture we do it alphabetically  :) i changed the code.
thanks for suggestion :)